# Excel Line Graph From Two Tables

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I am trying to make a line graph with information from two different tables and my second line (orange color) is plotting on the wrong dates. The purpose of this graph is to show fluctuation in demand over the last two weeks. The dates where the orange line should be plotting should be 7/14/23, 7/18/23 and 7/28/23 but when I try to change the horizontal axis dates it switches to the dates from the 1st table (blue color) and vise versa when I change the dates the blue line plots on the orange table dates.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a way for me to plot both lines on their respective dates? Attached is a screenshot of the data tables and line graph and screenshots of the formulas for each line on the graph.

**Screenshot of data tables and Line Chart**
[image: Screenshot of data tables and Line Chart]

**Screenshot of data tables and Line Chart**
[image: Formula for Blue Line on Chart]

**Formula for Orange Line on Chart**
[image: Formula for Orange Line on Chart]

Comment: It's probably worthwhile to combine both tables into one and make the chart from there

Comment: Hello, I was able to combine the tables into one and made the chart work! Thank you for the advice.